# Forced CSS rule via Javascript is partially applied

Tags: javascript, css

I've this following HTML:

```
<li id="telephone"><a href="tel:938409"target="_blank"><img  src="https://playground.air-srl.com/icombanner/telico.png"/></a></li>
                    <li id="ico"><a href="./cmbmodal.php?servizio=TEST" target="_blank"><img src="https://playground.air-srl.com/icombanner/cmbico.png"/></a></li>
                    <li id="status"></li>
                    <li  id="icon"><a href="https://m.me/xxxx/" target="_blank"><img src="https://playground.air-srl.com/icombanner/fbico.png"/></a></li>

                    <li id="icon">
                        <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=03480224&text=Buongiorno, sono interessato alla vostra offerta." target="_blank">
                            <img src="https://playground.air-srl.com/icombanner/whaico.png"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
```

On a "onload" JS Function, I'm forcing the CSS in this way:

```
document.getElementById("telephone").style="display: block";
                        document.getElementById("icon").style="display: block";
                        document.getElementById("status").style="display: block";
```

The result is that I've three "icon" elements as you can see, but onlythe first has this forced stye rule applied.

Any suggestion about why isn't it completely applied?

Comment: Edit: the second "li" element on HTML code has still "icon" id instead of "ico".

Comment: IDs must be unique.

Comment: id attribute intended to be unique. Browser doesn't expect you to have more than one element with id `icon`. Use `class="icon"` and `document.querySelectorALl('.icon').forEach(element => element.style = "display: block;"`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've forget this rule!

Comment: @LorenzoNeri: No, even after the edit, there are two `id="icon"` in the above (and one `id="eco"`).

Comment: @Crowder: I've forget this rule. Thank you for your explaination!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give your icons a `class` instead of `id` (`id`s must be unique in the DOM).
 `class="icon"` then

```
var icons = document.getElementsByClassName('icon');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(icons, function(icon){
  icon.style.display = "block";
});
```

> *document.getElementsByClassName()* returns an **array-like object** of all child elements which have all of the given class names

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 elements with the same ID. ID is unique attribute use class instead:

```
<li  class="icon" ...
```

And change the selector in the JS function to:

```
(".icon")
```

Comment: There **has** to be a dupetarget for this.

Comment: I consider myself a Stackoverflow  noob. Am I not supposed to answer semi trivial questions but look for a duplicate thread instead ?

Comment: Yes. The goal of SO is to build a database of useful programming information. Ideally, there'd be **one** question and set of answers which all duplicates would point to. The system falls short of that ideal, not least because it doesn't make finding duplicates very easy and doesn't reward doing so (two critical flaws in SO in my view), but that's the goal.