# Javascript return an empty array but with two elements in it

Tags: javascript

I am little confused. When i try to get elements like `document.getElementsByClassName('html5gallery-tn-image-0')` what i get is that:
[image]

These are the elements i am searching for but instead the array says that it is empty. Can you explain me please why is that way and can i reach the elements in this array? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is not an array, but a node list (array-like). That looks different in dev tools. It is not empty.

Comment: Logical! Thank you very much!

Comment: Try this: `document.getElementsByClassName('html5gallery-tn-image-0')[0]` and let me know what you get.

Comment: I've already answered to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45077222/forced-css-rule-via-javascript-is-partially-applied/45077431#45077431

Comment: Nothing again :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several things going on that explains this behaviour:

1. You are performing the `console.log` at a moment that there are no such elements yet in the document. Probably the JavaScript executes before the document is ready. This explains why `temp[0]` is undefined.
2. The `HTMLCollection` returned by `getElementsByClassName` is not an array and has some magical behaviour: it is a *live* collection. So if the document gets an additional element of that class, it will magically appear in that `temp` collection without you touching it!
3. When you log an object to console, the Chrome dev tools will not collect all the object properties at that moment, but asynchronously. This means that although at the time of logging the collection *was* empty, it no longer is when you click on the dev tools to see what is in the collection.

See the first two points illustrated in this script:

```js
var temp = document.getElementsByClassName('html5gallery-tn-image-0');
console.log(temp.length); // 0

// add the class to the element
mydiv.className = "html5gallery-tn-image-0";
console.log(temp.length); // 1
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

#### Solution

Move your JavaScript code so that it only executes when the document is completely loaded. Either:

- Move your Javascript to the end of the `body` tag, or
- wrap the code in a `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { ... });` callback.

Answer (score 0):

In your console.log it returns with two image elements on it, so it not empty.

Comment: `[]` is an array, `{}` would be an object.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollection, which has a few special properties. One of them is, that the content of that array-like thing gets updated as soon as the DOM gets updated. Additionally in Chrome the part which shows "[]" got calculated as soon as you pressed enter, but the content (those two elements) get evaluated only when you expand the output.